# How to assign entry type for two different parameters

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I wanna ask how can I assign entry type 10 for the account receivable and 20 for account payable in array, because my api is using xml so i need to pass array into it.

This is my database look

```
NAME|Purchase|  Sales | Tax | Discount | EntryType|
AR  | 303-00 | 200-00 | 6.0 |    3.0   |    10    |
AP  | 200-00 | 800-00 | 4.0 |    2.0   |    20    |
```

When I insert it will save into the same table but differentiate them with the entry type. Im failed to pass the data at array there. I dont know how to assign specific value for them. Anyone please help me? Stuck at this question very long time already.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btnUpdateAccControl").click(function(e) {

          var arrayItem = [];
          var sArrayItem = "";
// at here how can I assign entry type 10 for the account receivable and 20 for account payable in array, because my api is using xml so i need to pass array into it.
          $(.row),function(index, value) {

            let item = {
              Purchase: $(".col-purchase").val(),
              Sales: $(".col-sales").val(),
              Tax: $(".col-tax").val(),
              Discount: $(".col-discount").val(),
            }
            arrayItem.push(item)
          }); console.log(arrayItem)

        sArrayItem = JSON.stringify(arrayItem);

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "UpdateAccControl",
          data: JSON.stringify({
            sArrayItem
          }),
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(result) {
            if (result.d.indexOf(".aspx") != -1)
              window.location.href = result.d;
            else
              showPopup(result);
          },
          failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
          }
        });
      });
```

```html
<!-- Row -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="card custom-card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h5>Account Receivable</h5>
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group text-left">
              <label>Purchase</span></label>
              <input class="form-control col-purchase" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-left">
              <label>Sales</label>
              <input class="form-control col-sales" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-left">
              <label>Tax</label>
              <input class="form-control col-tax" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-left">
              <label>Discount</label>
              <input class="form-control col-discount" type="text" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h5>Account Payable</h5>
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group text-left">
              <label>Purchase</span></label>
              <input class="form-control col-purchase" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-left">
              <label>Sales</label>
              <input class="form-control col-sales" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-left">
              <label>Tax</label>
              <input class="form-control col-tax" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-left">
              <label>Discount</label>
              <input class="form-control col-discount" type="text" required>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <div class="btn ripple btn-info" id='btnUpdateAccControl'><i class="fe fe-plus-circle"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Row -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the value of `h5` element inside your `col-md-6` is `Account Receivable` or not depending this assign value `10` or `20` to `EntryType`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#btnUpdateAccControl").click(function(e) {
  var arrayItem = [];
  var sArrayItem = "";
  //loop through each divs
  $(" .card-body .row .col-md-6").each(function(index, value) {
    //use this .find to get only required value one col-md-6
    arrayItem.push({
      Purchase: $(this).find(".col-purchase").val(),
      Sales: $(this).find(".col-sales").val(),
      Tax: $(this).find(".col-tax").val(),
      Discount: $(this).find(".col-discount").val(),
      EntryType: $(this).find("h5:first").text().trim() == "Account Receivable" ? 10 : 20 //check if h5 is acc rec or payable
    })
  });
  console.log(arrayItem)
  //other codes..
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="card custom-card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h5>Account Receivable</h5>
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group text-left">
              <label><span>Purchase</span></label>
              <input class="form-control col-purchase" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-left">
              <label>Sales</label>
              <input class="form-control col-sales" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-left">
              <label>Tax</label>
              <input class="form-control col-tax" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-left">
              <label>Discount</label>
              <input class="form-control col-discount" type="text" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h5>Account Payable</h5>
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group text-left">
              <label><span>Purchase</span></label>
              <input class="form-control col-purchase" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-left">
              <label>Sales</label>
              <input class="form-control col-sales" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-left">
              <label>Tax</label>
              <input class="form-control col-tax" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-left">
              <label>Discount</label>
              <input class="form-control col-discount" type="text" required>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <div class="btn ripple btn-info" id='btnUpdateAccControl'><i class="fe fe-plus-circle">Send</i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```